# nutch: crawling through goagent proxy

Tags: proxy, nutch

I'm learning crawling pages with Nutch now. But there is a problem that I can't fix.
I want to crawl pages via a local proxy server, which address is 127.0.0.1:8087. And the server works well(my FireFox can use it well). In the Nutch-conf file conf/nutch-site.xml, I added some properties as follows:

**http.agent.host-->   127.0.0.1**

**http.proxy.port-->8087**

My local server doesn't need any authentication.

Nutch can run successfully but do not request via the proxy.

THANKS.

Answer (score 4):

just add these properties to nutch-site.xml (replace XXXX with the correct values)

```
<property>
  <name>http.proxy.host</name>
  <value>XXXXXX</value>
  <description>The proxy hostname.  If empty, no proxy is used.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>http.proxy.port</name>
  <value>XXXXXXXX</value>
  <description>The proxy port.</description>
</property>
```

And if you need auth:

```
<property>
  <name>http.proxy.username</name>
  <value></value>
  <description>Username for proxy. This will be used by
  'protocol-httpclient', if the proxy server requests basic, digest
  and/or NTLM authentication. To use this, 'protocol-httpclient' must
  be present in the value of 'plugin.includes' property.
  NOTE: For NTLM authentication, do not prefix the username with the
  domain, i.e. 'susam' is correct whereas 'DOMAIN\susam' is incorrect.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>http.proxy.password</name>
  <value></value>
  <description>Password for proxy. This will be used by
  'protocol-httpclient', if the proxy server requests basic, digest
  and/or NTLM authentication. To use this, 'protocol-httpclient' must
  be present in the value of 'plugin.includes' property.
  </description>
</property>
```

Comment: make sure you are using protocol-httpclient and not protocol-http for the fetch plugin

Answer (score 1):

I faced somewhat similar problem. Not sure if it is the same. I set path for these from terminal and ran Nutch. It worked fine. I did not do any other additional settings in Nutch. It worked on Ubuntu but somehow it is not working on mac. Let me know if it works.

```
    export http_proxy=http://server-ip:port/
    export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8087/
    export http_proxy=http://proxy-server.mycorp.com:8087/
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply~~ I just fixed the problem which resulted from my carelessness. The http.agent.host should be http.proxy.host... I hope you not making the same mistake. Thanks!~

Comment: @ailen Thanks for adding the comment with the solution. I suggest you also edit your post to show the correct config file setting so people don't accidentally mimic your mistake.